# Design issues and implementing Enumerable.AsEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumeration, farpoint-spread

How can i make a datatype return `IEnumerable<datatype>` if it does not have `AsEnumerable()` method. For example:

```
FarPointSpread1.ActiveSheet.Rows[e.Row]
```

does not contain `AsEnumerable()` so i cannot do this

```
FarPointSpread1.ActiveSheet.Rows[e.Row].AsEnumerable()
```

`e.Row` is the current row in the spread's activesheet and i am expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> = FarPointSpread1.ActiveSheet.Rows[e.Row].AsEnumerable();
```

I want to iterate over all fields in a row and set values on runtime - which will come from database.
Is there a way i can achieve this? If there is some workaround please let me know with some examples. Even if the example cannot be shown using Farpoint - any other kind of example is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really explain _what you are trying to do_, only that _what_ you are trying to do doesn't work. I would not expect to be able to iterate over a `Row` object. Doesn't it expose an enumerable `Cells` property? Or do you want to iterate over all rows? Then you shouldn't use the indexer `[e.Row]`, as that returns a single row.

Comment: What do you expect to loop through a row? its cells? I don't really know through about the actual type of `Row` in your code, but if it has some cells collection, you can implement some extension method

Comment: @CodeCaster - i want to be able to do this - 
            `IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> nthRow = fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Cells[e.Row].AsEnumerable();
            nthRow.ToList().ForEach(r =>
                r.SetField( "A"  , "Test" );
            )`

Comment: You're showing code again, not _explaining what you want it to do_. Do you want to iterate over all rows to set a field, or do you want to iterate over all fields in a row?

Comment: @CodeCaster - i want to iterate over all fields in a row and set values on runtime - which will come from database

Comment: Then see if the `Rows[e.Row]` object contains a `Cells` property.

Comment: Even that does not have AsEnumerable... - i want to be able to use Linq - i do not want to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). An example without FarPoint is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Values { get; set; }
}

public static class TestClassExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> AsEnumerable(this TestClass cls)
    {
        return cls.Values.AsEnumerable();
    }
}

// Call
var cls = new TestClass();
var enum = cls.AsEnumerable();
```

This sample shows the general structure of an extension method - of course it is very simplified as TestClass contains the values already in a matching form. You'd implement the extension method so that it contains the logic to enumerable the rows for FarPoint.
As far as I understand your question, you want to extend a single row and enumerate the values of the fields. You'd use the data type of the row and enumerate the fields in the extension methods.