# Runtime error on casting Array to string Enumerator

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration, farpoint-spread

This is a follow up question to [`Design issues and implementing Enumerable.AsEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324797/design-issues-and-implementing-enumerable-asenumerablefarpoint-win-spread-row)

I have casted my farpoint row to a 2 d object array like this:

```
object[,] nthRow = fpSpread2.ActiveSheet.GetArray(e.Row, e.Column, 1, FarPointSpread1.ActiveSheet.ColumnCount);
```

I try to cast this to string so that i can apply Linq but i get the following error at runtime:

```
IEnumerator<string> narry = (IEnumerator<string>)nthRow.GetEnumerator();
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'ArrayEnumerator' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.String]'.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: @riezebosch - it does not answer for 2 d arrays?

Comment: What data would you ike to return if there are more than one column in the data? Concatenated text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for multidimensional arrays you can call `Cast<T>` on it.

```
using System.Linq;
...
nthRow.Cast<string>().GetEnumerator()    // returns IEnumerator<string>
```

But each element in the array should actually be type `string`. If you want to do formatting like `ToString()`, you can first cast them into `object` and then call `Select<T>`.

Comment: I just need a single dimensional array from 0th index how can i get that?

Comment: @Lohit that cannot be easily done in C# given a multidimensional array. You have to copy the array elements. But, if you only want one row, **why don't you specify the row number when you call `fpSpread2.ActiveSheet.GetArray`**?